# typescript .d.ts file not recognized by typescript but vsc

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, definition

### Update:

it isnt a typescript, but ts-node "issue"

i answered to myself so if ure still interested in the "issue" - read further :)

sorry for the confusion

---

maybe I have a TOTALLY wrong idea of the index.d.ts file.. but my idea was, that i can declare types within it and they are then "globally defined", so i dont have to redeclare them everywhere i use them (file a.ts and b.ts)

structure:

```
root
  src
    a.ts
    b.ts
  node_modules
  tsconfig.json
  index.d.ts
  package.json
```

for example i have a index.d.ts file:

```
type XYZType = { test: string }
```

in my ./src/a.ts I have:

```
const x: XYZType = { test: 'hello' }
console.log(x)
```

in my ./src/b.ts I have:

```
const x: XYZType = { test: 'world' }
console.log(x)
```

however vsc (Visual Studio Code) **doesn't** complain about missing XYZType Type.. but when I try to let typescript compile, it does...:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XYZType'.
```

and points to file a.ts and b.ts

so.. to be obvious.. it looks like I do something wrong..

i followed the little example from levelup [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-set-up-a-typescript-node-js-app-in-5-minutes-93ffee3b1768)

so my **tsconfig.json** looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

i'm using:

```
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
```

i found a lot of stack overflow requests with the same title.. but totally different content (own package declarations?) so this is why it confuses me and i have the feeling im totally wrong with the approach im looking for

hope anybody can help and explain whats wrong :/

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok wow - it isnt a **typescript**, but an **ts-node** issue

in the example link the package.json script "dev" is setup like

```
"scripts": { 
  "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts", 
}
```

but has to be:

```
"scripts": { 
  "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' --files src/index.ts", 
}
```

('**--files**' has to be added)

sorry for the confusion but hopefully it helps someone running in the same issue :)

Comment: Thanks, I searched everywhere for an answer but couldn't figure out why until I saw this

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My VS was able to detect *.d.ts file but in compiler I was getting error.
The only fix which I needed was to add `--files` in the package.json script for running the local server. Thanks to @skizzle

Example -

```json
"exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --files ./src/index.ts",
```